# Strange behavior in GCC-6.3.0

Tags: c

I'm currently implementing the Data Encryption Standard (DES) in C.

DES uses multiple permutation functions, all of which are done by calling the `permute` on an entry value, a permutation table and the permutation table's size.
It returns the permuted bits of the entry, based on the permutation table's entries (the way I understand C arrays, whether the be static or dynamic, is that they correspond to an address in memory).

The encryption/decryption process is straight forward, as both are done by calling the same function
(here: `des_crypt`) and reversing the subkeys given by the DES' key schedule (here: `des_ksa`) in the case of decryption.
In `des_crypt`, there is a call to `f(r, k)` which corresponds to a cipher function defined above.

In debugging this code (mostly, making it run), I observed that it would "crash".
By "crash", I mean that the code flow would stop before printf-ing the debugging information: my guess was that it was caused by a segfault.

Here comes the strange part (more like the nonsense).

The code was compiled using `gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0`. After execution, it seemed like that the `permute` table's entries cant be accessed when in `f`, `k ^= permute(r, E, 48)` is executed (doing `printf("%lu", t[i]);` causes the program to end abruptly, without printf-ing the array's `i`th element), i.e. the supposed segfault.

But it seemed like `gcc` successfully compiled for many (@JohnBollinger, @adabsurdum, ...). As such, I found an online compiler: the program compiled & executed successfully.

In the previous versions, I also made multiple errors: the macros were missing parenthesis, I had some Undefined Behavior in the `swap` function, and the `permute` function didn't perform well due to my lack of understanding of the tables.

Correcting all this, by repeatedly compiling & executing the program with those changes yielded the correct result.

However, even if I am now able to compile & execute the program on the previous machine, it yields wrong results: probably because of some conversion issue.
I do think that this matter is of no importance and consider it resolved.

I'll also update the title accordingly.

For reference, here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ROTL(x, l, w) ((((x) << (l)) | ((x) >> ((w) - (l)))) & (1 << (w)) - (l))
#define ROTR(x, l, w) ((((x) >> (l)) | ((x) << ((w) - (l)))) & (1 << (w)) - (l))


void swap(void* a, void* b, size_t size)
{
    char temp;
    
    if(!a || !b)
        return;
    while(size)
    {
        temp = *(char*)a;
        *(char*)a = *(char*)b;
        *(char*)b = temp;
        a = (void*)((char*)a + 1); // As void pointer increment is a non portable extension of GCC.
        b = (void*)((char*)b + 1);
        size--;
    }
    
    return;
}


//----- DES -----


#define DES_ROUNDS 16


const uint8_t S1[64] = {
    14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7,
    0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8,
    4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0,
    15, 12, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, 11, 3, 14, 10, 0, 6, 13
};

const uint8_t S2[64] = {
    15, 1, 8, 14, 6, 11, 3, 4, 9, 7, 2, 13, 12, 0, 5, 10,
    3, 13, 4, 7, 15, 2, 8, 14, 12, 0, 1, 10, 6, 9, 11, 5,
    0, 14, 7, 11, 10, 4, 13, 1, 5, 8, 12, 6, 9, 3, 2, 15,
    13, 8, 10, 1, 3, 15, 4, 2, 11, 6, 7, 12, 0, 5, 14, 9
};

const uint8_t S3[64] = {
    10, 0, 9, 14, 6, 3, 15, 5, 1, 13, 12, 7, 11, 4, 2, 8,
    13, 7, 0, 9, 3, 4, 6, 10, 2, 8, 5, 14, 12, 11, 15, 1,
    13, 6, 4, 9, 8, 15, 3, 0, 11, 1, 2, 12, 5, 10, 14, 7,
    1, 10, 13, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 15, 14, 3, 11, 5, 2, 12
};

const uint8_t S4[64] = {
    7, 13, 14, 3, 0, 6, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8, 5, 11, 12, 4, 15,
    13, 8, 11, 5, 6, 15, 0, 3, 4, 7, 2, 12, 1, 10, 14, 9,
    10, 6, 9, 0, 12, 11, 7, 13, 15, 1, 3, 14, 5, 2, 8, 4,
    3, 15, 0, 6, 10, 1, 13, 8, 9, 4, 5, 11, 12, 7, 2, 14
};

const uint8_t S5[64] = {
    2, 12, 4, 1, 7, 10, 11, 6, 8, 5, 3, 15, 13, 0, 14, 9,
    14, 11, 2, 12, 4, 7, 13, 1, 5, 0, 15, 10, 3, 9, 8, 6,
    4, 2, 1, 11, 10, 13, 7, 8, 15, 9, 12, 5, 6, 3, 0, 14,
    11, 8, 12, 7, 1, 14, 2, 13, 6, 15, 0, 9, 10, 4, 5, 3
};

const uint8_t S6[64] = {
    12, 1, 10, 15, 9, 2, 6, 8, 0, 13, 3, 4, 14, 7, 5, 11,
    10, 15, 4, 2, 7, 12, 9, 5, 6, 1, 13, 14, 0, 11, 3, 8,
    9, 14, 15, 5, 2, 8, 12, 3, 7, 0, 4, 10, 1, 13, 11, 6,
    4, 3, 2, 12, 9, 5, 15, 10, 11, 14, 1, 7, 6, 0, 8, 13
};

const uint8_t S7[64] = {
    4, 11, 2, 14, 15, 0, 8, 13, 3, 12, 9, 7, 5, 10, 6, 1,
    13, 0, 11, 7, 4, 9, 1, 10, 14, 3, 5, 12, 2, 15, 8, 6,
    1, 4, 11, 13, 12, 3, 7, 14, 10, 15, 6, 8, 0, 5, 9, 2,
    6, 11, 13, 8, 1, 4, 10, 7, 9, 5, 0, 15, 14, 2, 3, 12
};

const uint8_t S8[64] = {
    13, 2, 8, 4, 6, 15, 11, 1, 10, 9, 3, 14, 5, 0, 12, 7,
    1, 15, 13, 8, 10, 3, 7, 4, 12, 5, 6, 11, 0, 14, 9, 2,
    7, 11, 4, 1, 9, 12, 14, 2, 0, 6, 10, 13, 15, 3, 5, 8,
    2, 1, 14, 7, 4, 10, 8, 13, 15, 12, 9, 0, 3, 5, 6, 11
};


uint8_t s(box, block) // 6-bit block, box is S[1-8]
uint8_t *box, block;
{
    
    block &= 0x3F;
    
    return box[((block & 0b11) << 4) + ((block & 0b111100) >> 2)];
}


// All substitution boxes are false.
const uint8_t IP[64] = {
    57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1,
    59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3,
    61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5,
    63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7,
    56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0,
    58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2,
    60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4,
    62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6
};


const uint8_t FP[64] = {
    39, 7, 47, 15, 55, 23, 63, 31,
    38, 6, 46, 14, 54, 22, 62, 30,
    37, 5, 45, 13, 53, 21, 61, 29,
    36, 4, 44, 12, 52, 20, 60, 28,
    35, 3, 43, 11, 51, 19, 59, 27,
    34, 2, 42, 10, 50, 18, 58, 26,
    33, 1, 41, 9, 49, 17, 57, 25,
    32, 0, 40, 8, 48, 16, 56, 24
};

const uint8_t E[48] = {
    31, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
    27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0
};

const uint8_t P[32] = {
    15, 6, 19, 20,
    28, 11, 27, 16,
    0, 14, 22, 25,
    4, 17, 30, 9,
    1, 7, 23, 13,
    31, 26, 2, 8,
    18, 12, 29, 5,
    21, 10, 3, 24
};

const uint8_t PC1C[28] = {
    56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8,
    0, 57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17,
    9, 1, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26,
    18, 10, 2, 59, 51, 43, 35
};

const uint8_t PC1D[28] = {
    62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14,
    6, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21,
    13, 5, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28,
    20, 12, 4, 27, 19, 11, 3
};

const uint8_t PC2[48] = {
    13, 16, 10, 23, 0, 4,
    2, 27, 14, 5, 20, 9,
    22, 18, 11, 3, 25, 7,
    15, 6, 26, 19, 12, 1,
    40, 51, 30, 36, 46, 54,
    29, 39, 50, 44, 32, 47,
    43, 48, 38, 55, 33, 52,
    45, 41, 49, 35, 28, 31
};


uint8_t getls(i) // gives the number of left shifts needed based on the iterno, quickly done, should find faster alternatives
uint8_t i;
{
    uint8_t p;
    
    if(i == 1)
        return 1;
    p = (i - 2) / 7;
    if((int)(7 * p + 2) < (int)i)
        return 2;
    
    return 1;
}


uint64_t permute(x, t, s)
uint64_t x;
uint8_t *t, s;
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint64_t r;
    
    // i-th bit of input is the t[i]-th bit of output
    r = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
        r |= ((x >> i) & 0b1) << t[i]; // 0b1 Kenobi!
    
    return r;
}


uint32_t f(r, k)
uint32_t r;
uint64_t k;
{
    uint32_t temp;
    uint8_t i;
    const uint8_t *S[8] = {
        S1, S2, S3, S4,
        S5, S6, S7, S8
    };
    
    k ^= permute(r, E, 48); // Doesn't get past this point.
    temp = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        temp |= s(S[i], (k >> ((7 - k) * 6)) & 0b111111) & 0b1111;
        temp <<= 4;
    }
    
    return (uint32_t)permute(temp, P, 32);
}


uint64_t* des_ksa(key, rounds)
uint64_t key;
uint8_t rounds;
{
    uint64_t *subkeys;
    uint32_t c, d;
    uint8_t i, l;
    
    rounds &= 0x7F; // Make sure there are no overflows.
    subkeys = (uint64_t*)malloc(rounds * sizeof(uint64_t));
    if(!subkeys)
        return NULL;
    c = permute(key, PC1C, 28);
    d = permute(key, PC1D, 28);
    for(i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
    {
        l = getls(i);
        c = ROTL(c, l, 28);
        d = ROTL(d, l, 28);
        subkeys[i] = permute(((uint64_t)c << 28) | d, PC2, 48);
    }
    
    return subkeys;
}


/*
    :en: keep the subkeys' order as given by the des_ksa();
    :de: reverse the subkeys' order (relative to the one given by the des_ksa());
*/
uint64_t des_crypt(subkeys, block, rounds)
uint64_t *subkeys, block;
uint8_t rounds;
{
    uint32_t l, r, copy;
    uint8_t i;
    
    rounds &= 0x7F; // Takes care of overflows.
    block = permute(block, IP, 64);
    l = block >> 32;
    r = block;
    for(i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
    {
        copy = r;
        r = l ^ f(r, subkeys[i]);
        l = copy;
    }
    block = permute(((uint64_t)r << 32) | l, FP, 64);
    
    return block;
}


int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    uint64_t key, block, temp;
    uint8_t i;
    uint64_t *subkeys;
    
    key = 0x9649f3e19e66266a;
    subkeys = NULL;
    block = 0x68036386d860cba4;
    
    subkeys = des_ksa(key, DES_ROUNDS);
    if(!subkeys)
    {
        printf("error: failed to generate the appropriate subkeys");
        return 1;
    }
    
    temp = des_crypt(subkeys, block, DES_ROUNDS);
    for(i = 0; i < DES_ROUNDS >> 1; i++)
        swap(&subkeys[i], &subkeys[DES_ROUNDS - 1 - i], sizeof(uint64_t));
    printf("%lu vs. %lu\n", block, des_crypt(subkeys, temp, DES_ROUNDS));
    free(subkeys);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think "cant I access the permutation table's elements"? What are the symptoms?

Comment: If you are getting a segfault then it is surprising that the program does not terminate.  If you are debugging by running the program under the control of a debugger, then it is surprising that your debugger does not inform you about the segfault, either.

Comment: If you're *not* running under control of a debugger, then now is the time to start.  That's how you can figure out at least *where* the program is stalling, and probably also why and how.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for your time. My guess is that I can't access the table's elements as when I try (in any given expression, more often `printf` calls), the program simply stops executing.

Comment: K&R C was invented half a century ago. Is there a reason for not using ANSI compatible source code?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your time. By "debugging" I meant finding the statements that are supposed to cause the "crash", more often by checking whether `printf` statements are executed or not. I do not KNOW how to use a debugger as I do this on my free time.

Comment: `uint8_t s(box, block) // 6-bit block, box is S[1-8]
uint8_t *box, block;` Any reason you use 30 year old syntax? `box[((block & 0b11) << 4) + ((block & 0b111100) >> 2)];` How about adding a simple `size_t index = ((block & 0b11) << 4) + ((block & 0b111100) >> 2); assert(index < the_size_of_box)` everywhere you access any array?

Comment: @harper Thank you for your time. In which sense do you mean that this is not "ANSI compatible source code"?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your time. Could I ask why my coding style is relevant in the matter?

Comment: If it so happens that the cause of the crashes isn't related to array accesses, I will update the question's title accordingly.

Comment: `Could I ask why my coding style is relevant in the matter?` It is not relevant.

Comment: While everyone's entitled to their own coding style, these K&R style function definitions are like asking questions in Old English. People are going to have a hard time understanding what you're saying, it's a long-extinct dialect of C.

Comment: @MasumiMuramoto, nobody is born knowing how to use a debugger.  Investing a little time now to learn will pay off if you plan to continue with your coding hobby.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your time. I understand. Unfortunately, the way I learned C was through a very old man whose reason for using the "K&R style function definitions" was to be as precise and concise as possible, while also allowing an easy understanding of the underlying algorithm.

Comment: With respect to K&R style function definitions: that is ***not*** a mere style question.  Function calling semantics are a bit different for functions declared without prototypes (K&R style) than for those declared with.  Also, the K&R style is no longer part of ISO C (it was removed in C23), though compilers are likely to continue supporting it for some time yet.

Comment: Sure, but you don't just learn something once and be done with it, learning is a process. Any argument that K&R is somehow more "concise" has been disproven with time. There's a reason ANSI simplified a lot of things in C89. As in 1989. As in 41 years ago today. This isn't even accounting for a multitude of new quality of life features that have been built into C since then.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your time. I don't reject the learning process, simply would like to shed light on the value of difference. As such, I aim to continue (for the time being) with this coding style.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your time. I use Notepad++ to write code and MinGW to compile it. This minimalist setting is due to me not being able to have a computer. Do you have any debugger's name in mind?

Comment: `gdb` is a command-line debugger that you may already have installed as part of MinGW (it is certainly *available* from both MinGW and MinGW-w64).  It is quite popular among those who use the GNU toolchain (as you do in MinGW).

Comment: Please take the time to create a *minimal* reproducible example. If you think that you cannot access the elements of an array, it shouldn't take nearly as much code as you've shown to demonstrate that. Removing everything that's not directly related to your question will make it much easier to help you, and you may even discover in that process that the problem isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Doing pointer arithmetics with `void*` is a non-portable extension of GCC that is not supported by the standard.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for your time. I'd like to point out that ALL the code is needed to understand the underlying problem as the example IS the code. It is reproducible as when you do compile the program, executing it should result in a crash. I'd also like to point out that even though this is my first time on stack overflow, I don't have time to lose. As such, I am as exhaustive as possible when posting, in respect to every person who takes the time to review my question.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you for your time. I will switch the cast in `swap` to avoid any unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your time. I'll start using `gdb` in my debugging sessions, but still as a last resort (i.e. when checking the execution or non-execution of `printf` statements is of no use).

Comment: Your program does not segfault or stall for me.  However, when I compile it with warning options turned up high (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), I get some interesting warnings (plus many other less interesting ones).  GCC points out that your `swap()` function has undefined behavior when it updates pointers `a` and `b` via expressions of the general form `x = ... operators ... ++x`.  That could very well be the source of the problem.

Comment: You have undefined behavior in the `swap` function even ignoring the casts. This is UB due to attempting to modify `a` twice between sequence points: `a = ++a;`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your time. The `swap` function is only used on the latter part of the `main` function, where I attempt the decryption process on the `block`. But this part is never reached as the program terminates at the encryption process.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. You are probably right: the idea was to both make use of instruction sets that support the increment instruction (`inc` in x86 assembly) & avoid incrementing a `void*` pointer. I'll change it right away.

Comment: As this is your first post, please read about [mre]. You claim that you cannot read elements of an array, a **minimal** example of that would require only a few lines. if you're actually asking about accessing an array from the commented-out assembly, you still shouldn't need 15 arrays and a half dozen functions to demonstrate the issue. Eliminating everything that's not part of the actual problem helps us help you, but it's also a powerful debugging method that will help you isolate and identify problems on your own.

Comment: @tadman "As in 1989. As in 41 years ago today"  Ummmm...

Comment: @MasumiMuramoto If you want to benchmark code, or compare implementations for performance or memory usage reasons, you need to make full use of your compiler's optimizer.  `gcc des.c -o a` does not optimize much, so the code it emits will be nowhere near as performant as something like `gcc des.c -O3 -o a`.  And there are many, many other `gcc` optimization options that can and will result in different results.  And such optimizations are usually much faster and more efficiant than anything you will create with more complex code.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for your time. I included this much code as all of it describes exhaustively the Data Encryption Standard (DES) and could allow a deeper understanding of what I am trying to achieve. However, I do recognize that this much code is maybe TOO MUCH. As such, I'll review my post to change this feeling. I'd still like to point out that I KNOW what goes wrong, I just don't know WHY and HOW to change it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your time. I'd like to explain the reason of such choices: firstly, I despise letting a program choose how to optimize code, the reason being that in the worst case scenario, the compiler might produce faulty code that will take days on end to identify; secondly, "manual" optimization allows you to explore in more depths the inner workings of a CPU and/or of a compiler, finding new tricks to reduce both the memory usage & the number of instructions.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for your time. As I am unable to edit my previous comment, I'd like to apologize for my hot-headed behavior. It is hard to answer every single comment posted, and I feel like the critics aim more towards my own personal design choices (or, for what its worth, my old coding style) than a real comment asking, for example, precisions on the meaning of certain parts of code. This seems clearly illustrated by the all the fuss around the `swap` function, though I'm grateful for it as it allowed me to identify major design flaws.

Comment: _"I KNOW what goes wrong"_. I'm not sure of that. @JohnBollinger pointed out that the program compiled for him and did not segfault or stall when run. I compiled the current code (with UB `a = ++a` fixed): `$ gcc -Wall -Wextra des_2.c `. When run the output was on two lines: `: 7494943635681627044.` and `7494943635681627044 vs. 7494943635681627044.`

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. So the problem was the `swap` function? It seems strange as when I debugged it, it crashed on the `k ^= permute(r, E, 48);` line.

Comment: Also note that style choices are not completely irrelevant. I missed the `a = ++a` problem at first because it was obfuscated by casts and parentheses. WRT optimizers: it is a noble goal to seek to understand the machine, but optimizers are very good at what they do. Let them do their work, which relies on clear and idiomatic code constructs.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `swap` function was your problem; it was _a_ problem. When a program has undefined behavior the whole program is invalid.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. Would you care to include as an answer to this post the corrected code (as my version still crashes)?

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. I didn't realize it, I really learned something... May you still include your answer to this post?

Comment: Hmm. I wonder why your version still crashes. You probably did this, but are you certain that you have compiled and run the updated code? I copy-pasted what is posted now and compiled it with no changes. It is difficult to diagnose problems that can't be reproduced. I don't want to post an answer that doesn't actually answer your question.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. Indeed, I copy pasted the given (supposedly corrected code) and it still crashed... Can I have some precisions on the compiler you are using?

Comment: I compiled the previously mentioned code using an online compiler, it was compiled & executed with success; as such, it seems more like a compiler problem than an actual C error.

Comment: I am using gcc 12.2.0 on Debian Linux. You say that code crashes at `k ^= permute(r, E, 48);`. What makes you think that? Also, what makes you think that your code is unable to access static array elements? What happens specifically when "code flow stops"? Apologies if I have missed an earlier answer to these questions.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you again for your time. What makes me thing that the program crashes at `k ^= permute(r, E, 48);` is that when I manually debugged the program (i.e. manually inserting `printf` statements at supposedly faulty segments), I found out that the `printf` statement above the `k ^= permute(r, E, 48);` correctly executes, but the one below doesn't. Moreover, by doing this inside the `permute` function, I found out that the statement `printf("%lu", t[i]);` isn't executed, the program abruptly stops.

Comment: @adabsurdum """ The program stops means that I don't get any output as I'm supposed to.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. I am compiling any C code using MinGW GCC-6.3.0-1. I'll check whether there is a more up-to-date version and try to compile the file on it.

Comment: @MasumiMuramoto *the reason being that in the worst case scenario, the compiler might produce faulty code that will take days on end to identify*  If you're that worried about faulty code generation, stop using K&R-style functions.  With no function prototype, there's zero error checking done for function parameters and no way to ensure parameters get passed properly.

Comment: `printf("%lu", t[i]);` has undefined behavior. `t[i]` has type `uint8_t`, and this should be printed with the `PRIu8` macro, i.e., `printf("%" PRIu8, t[i]);`. And `des_crypt` returns a `uint64_t` which should be printed with `PRIu64` (as should `temp` and `block`), e.g., `printf(": %" PRIu64 ".\n", temp);`. These print macros are in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your time. "If you're that worried about faulty code generation, stop using K&R-style functions. With no function prototype, there's zero error checking done for function parameters and no way to ensure parameters get passed properly." Could you elaborate on that? Or indicate literature and/or material on the subject?

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. I wasn't aware of the format specifiers of `uint8_t` and `uint64_t`.

Comment: Alright, so I re-installed MinGW latest version for Windows 10. It still crashes. I'll update the post accordingly and compile the file using an online compiler.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. Still, I am SURE that the `printf("%lu", t[i]);` wasn't the cause of the crashes: even without this statement, the program still crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overcomplicate very simple operations. You asked if style matters - yes it does.

```
void swap(void* va, void* vb, size_t size)
{
    char temp;
    unsigned char *a = va;
    unsigned char *b = vb;
    
    if(a && b && size)
    {
        while(size--)
        {
            temp = *a;
            *a++ = *b;
            *b++ = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't easier to read than your one?

Macros are very dangerous, you forgot many parenthesises (for example around `x`). What will happen if one of the parameter will be `y++`? Use inline functions instead.

It is not an answer but it is hard to show the code in the comment.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The reason behind the `swap` function's design choices were to reduce the memory allocated & the number of instructions executed at runtime, although I am not sure it does.

Comment: @0___________ Thank you for your time. I shall revise the defined macros once again and keep in mind your very helpful comment.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your time. Although what you are pointing out stands true on systems where 64 bit registers are available, what about very restricted systems that only use 8 (or 16) bits registers? My goal was to make the `swap` function as portable as possible, while reducing both memory usage & instructions. I do realize that this might not be the case with the current function's definition, but it was the goal I was aiming at, while not diving to deep into assembly and instruction sets.

Comment: @tadman it does not have to faster, it has to be easier to read by **humans**. BTW compilers know how to optimize it well and your remark is false https://godbolt.org/z/sW8axYKxK

Comment: @0___________ Thank you for your time. I will compare both versions and come back to edit the post's content.

Comment: @MasumiMuramoto your one is simple written very badly and if full of redundant casts and assignments. the compiler does not care, people (including you ) do.

Comment: @0___________ Thank you for your time. If the people cant see the code's underlying workings, they don't care. This post being on a potential invalid array access, the `swap`'s definition doesn't matter as it was proven to be a valid implementation (both theoretically & through thorough testing) multiple time.

Comment: @MasumiMuramoto -- in your question you compare the assembly code for your original `swap` implementation with the assembly of the code posted in this answer, but these assembly listings appear to be unoptimized. I would be surprised if the results were significantly different if you had enabled compiler optimizations.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you for your time. Indeed, but could you check my answer to Andrew Henle and check if it answers your concerns?

Comment: May I know why the post's ranking is -1? How can a person diminish another's plea for help?